# Как заменить Обазначение маркера буквами на индекс от 0?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Использую waypoints все ок.но он отмеечает точки буквами что несовсем удобно ..Можноли заменить их на цифры ?покапался в гугле особого по теме ответа нету 
а вот и ссылка на сам   [waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints?hl=ru)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключевой момент - отменить отрисовку стандартных маркеров маршрута, а потом самим реализовать прорисовку маркеров маршрута

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers : true // не использовать маркеры
});

// ...............

if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    var markerCounter = 1; //счетчик маркеров
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    // добавим свои маркеры
    var route = response.routes[0];
    // маркер начала движения
    addMarker(route.legs[0].start_location, markerCounter++);
    // маркеры по всему маршруту, включая конец
    for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
      addMarker(route.legs[i].end_location, markerCounter++);
    }
 }

// ...............

/** создает маркер с числовым номером i */
function addMarker(position, i) {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + i + '|FF0000|000000',
    position: position,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Ссылка на рабочий пример: https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/WRqrjW

[image: маршрут с номерами вместо букв]

Чтобы нумерация шла с 0, поставьте тут 0 вместо 1

[image: начальный индекс нумерации]

Comment: Lukas Pierce ваш тестировщик кода не работает ...  по нажатию кнопки ниче не происходит .Еду домой дома детально рассмотрю

Comment: попробуйте из дома на ПК, добавил скрин

Comment: спасибо ,а то ломал голову ,нашел метод но он надписывал на маркере что не есть очень хорошо

Comment: Лукас у тебя Waypoint не отрабатывает попробуй сам увидишь

Comment: Ну ладно спасибо дальше дома доделаю )

Comment: теперь показывает информацию о сегментах маршрута

Comment: благодарю вас !!!это именно то что мне надо!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Надо копать сюда: `var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';`

Меняешь на: `var labels = '123456789';`

все должно работать

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels